# Deserializing xml to object causes an error

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order xmlns="urn:schemas-alibaba-com:billing-data" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Currency>USD</Currency>
   <Description>description</Description>
</Order>
```

I have the above xml string that I am trying to deserialize to an object.  This is an auto generated class.

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true,
                  Namespace = "urn:schemas-alibaba-com:billing-data")]
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="Order",
                  Namespace = "urn:schemas-alibaba-com:billing-data",
                  IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Order
{
    private string currencyField;

    private object descriptionField;
}
```

I am getting an exception:

```
Exception:    
{"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."}  
Inner exception :
{"<Order xmlns='urn:schemas-alibaba-com:billing-data'> was not expected."}
```

What am I missing here?  Below is the code to deserialize: line 3 throws the exception.

```
var xmlReader = new StringReader(xml_data);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));    
var instance = (Order)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

Comment: I did. but my xml has a namespace and hence I think this should not be throwing exception.

Comment: @keeda are you sure? That does work. Are you modifying the the xml content in memory...whatever you're passing in `xml_data`? Are you changing the encoding or something?

Comment: @Leo I am using the string straight up that I am fetching from a db. seems to be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test your xml content, that is ok.

Here is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Xml_ShouldBeDeserialized()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Order));
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\test.xml"))
    {
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        var order = obj as Order;
        Assert.IsNotNull(order);                
    }
}

[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true,
              Namespace = "urn:schemas-alibaba-com:billing-data")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Order",
                  Namespace = "urn:schemas-alibaba-com:billing-data",
                  IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Order
{
    private string currencyField;

    private object descriptionField;

    public string Currency { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I guess you might miss fields "Currency" and "Description", and they should be accessable,

Comment: How did this fix the error?!?!?!?! AFAIK, this doesn't solve the error he was getting...am I missing something?